# How to condition on the result of a test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ i.i.d. and write $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$.
Define the point hypotheses $H_0 : \mu = 0$ and $H_1 : \mu = \mu_1$ for some fixed $\mu_1 > 0$.
Define the test statistic $T(x) := \bar{x} \sqrt{n} / s(x)$.
Then $T(X) \sim_{H_0} t(n-1)$ and $T(X) \sim_{H_1} t(n-1, \mu_1 \sqrt{n}/\sigma)$,
where the latter is the $t$ distribution with the appropriate non-centrality parameter.

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $t_{1-\alpha}$ the $1-\alpha$ quantile of $t(n-1)$.
Then $\mathrm{Pr}(t_{1-\alpha} \leq T(X) \,\vert\, H_0) = \alpha$.
Denote $\beta := \mathrm{Pr}(T(X) < t_{1-\alpha} \,\vert\, H_1) = 1 -  \mathrm{Pr}(t_{1-\alpha} \leq T(X) \,\vert\, H_1)$.

Assume that we observe $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^n$, which yields $t^* := T(x^*)$
and assume moreover that $t_{1-\alpha} \leq t^*$.
Let us treat $H_0$ and $H_1$ as events.
We would like to know the odds of $H_1$ over $H_0$ conditioned on the observation of $x^*$,
given some fixed estimate of the unconditioned odds.

**Alternative 1 (A.1):** we simply say that the test is positive (at the $\alpha$ significance level with power $1-\beta$)
since the test statistic went past the critical value.
We hence condition on a positive test using Bayes' rule:
$$\frac{\mathrm{Pr}(H_1 \,\vert\, t_{1-\alpha} \leq T(X))}{\mathrm{Pr}(H_0 \,\vert\, t_{1-\alpha} \leq T(X))}
= \frac{\mathrm{Pr}(t_{1-\alpha} \leq T(X) \,\vert\, H_1)}{\mathrm{Pr}(t_{1-\alpha} \leq T(X) \,\vert\, H_0)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{Pr}(H_1)}{\mathrm{Pr}(H_0)}
= \frac{1-\beta}{\alpha} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{Pr}(H_1)}{\mathrm{Pr}(H_0)}$$
This seems appropriate when we treat the test as a black box, which only gives the "positive" and "negative" answers,
and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were obtained from simulations.
This is very similar to what happens with medical tests.

**Alternative 2 (A.2):** we condition on the fact that we obtained a test statistic of $t^*$ or larger:
$$\frac{\mathrm{Pr}(H_1 \,\vert\, t^* \leq T(X))}{\mathrm{Pr}(H_0 \,\vert\, t^* \leq T(X))}
= \frac{\mathrm{Pr}(t^* \leq T(X) \,\vert\, H_1)}{\mathrm{Pr}(t^* \leq T(X) \,\vert\, H_0)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{Pr}(H_1)}{\mathrm{Pr}(H_0)}$$
This can also be understood as conditioning on the $p$ value of the observation.

**Alternative 3 (A.3):** we condition on the fact that we obtained a test statistic of exactly $t^*$.
Considering an appropriate limit, this can be written as:
$$\frac{\mathrm{Pr}(H_1 \,\vert\, T(X) = t^*)}{\mathrm{Pr}(H_0 \,\vert\, T(X) = t^*)}
= \frac{f_1(t^*)}{f_0(t^*)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{Pr}(H_1)}{\mathrm{Pr}(H_0)}$$
Here, $f_i$ is the probability density function of the distribution of $T(X)$ under $H_i$.

A.1 follows the principle of setting a significance level in advance and not changing it later.
A.3 follows the principle of conditioning on all the available evidence
(although one may argue that $x^*$ and not $t^*$ is the available evidence,
but I don't know how to incorporate every aspect of it).
A.2 is something in between.

The graphs shown below give the factors $\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}$,
$\frac{\mathrm{Pr}(t^* \leq T(X) \,\vert\, H_1)}{\mathrm{Pr}(t^* \leq T(X) \,\vert\, H_0)}$,
and $\frac{f_1(t^*)}{f_0(t^*)}$ for $\alpha = 0.05$ and $t^*$ ranging from $t_{1-\alpha}$ to $t_{1-\alpha}+1$,
with $n=10$ and for $\mu_1,\sigma \in \{0.5, 1, 2\}$.
The [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0kjd7h0eyo0oo6/crossvalidated-2017.12.17.R?dl=0) is available (Dropbox link).

A.1 (red) is always more pessimistic about $H_1$ than A.2 (green),
so we can use the factor from A.1 for a lower bound on the factor in A.2.

A.3 (blue) is substantially smaller than A.1 or A.2 for test statistics close to the critical value
and when $\sigma$ is small compared to $\mu_1$.
Particularly alarming are the cases $(\mu_1,\sigma)=(1,0.5)$
and $(\mu_1,\sigma)=(2,0.5)$ and $(\mu_1,\sigma)=(2,1)$.
Here, conditioning as per A.3 is (strongly) in favor of $H_0$,
even though the test is positive with respect to the significance level $\alpha$.

*What arguments would you give in favor of each of the alternatives?*

[image: comparison of the three alternatives]

What I have stumbled upon here is perhaps nothing more than a version of Lindley's Paradox: the test is positive (that is, in favor of $H_1$) in NHST terms, but the likelihood ratio tells a different story. However, this does not answer the question *why A.1 is popular in current literature*, for example:

- Ioannidis, "Why Most Published Research Findings Are False", 2005, doi:10.1371/journal.pmed.0020124
- O’Brien and Castelloe, "Sample-Size Analysis for Traditional Hypothesis Testing: Concepts and Issues", Chapter 10 in "Pharmaceutical Statistics Using SAS", 2007

On the other hand, the following are clearly in favor of A.3:

- Hooper, "The Bayesian interpretation of a P-value depends only weakly
  on statistical power in realistic situations", 2009, doi:10.1016/j.jclinepi.2009.02.004
- Colquhoun, "The reproducibility of research and the misinterpretation of p-values", 2017, doi:0.1098/rsos.171085

The first, in a section called "Problems with the diagnostic testing argument", argues against A.1 by saying that "if we only record that $P < \alpha$ we are throwing away evidence." Regarding A.2, it is said that  "this is not the same as making use of the precise P-value". I guess this is meant in the same way: we should not throw away evidence.

Comment: I think it's correct. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution#Use_in_power_analysis). I have uploaded a [quick'n'dirty simulation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1pgzkpijv28bzr/noncentral-t-2017.11.07.R?dl=0), which agrees with the claim. Am I missing something?

Comment: OK, apologies, I just do not use the same definition of a $t(\nu,\mu,\tau)$ distribution!